# Converting a string from long to short based on logic in python

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I have multiple long values like the following in a column in pandas dataframe (an example) -

```py
((Type=Food & Value1=Fruit & Value2=Apple) or (Type=Food & Value1=Fruit & Value2=Banana) or (Type=Food & Value1=Vegetable & Value2=Carrot) or (Type=Food & Value1=Vegetable & Value2=Tomato))
```

I want to convert it to -

```py
((Type=Food & Value1=Fruit & Value2 = Apple|Banana) or (Type=Food & Value1=Vegetable & Value2= Carrot|Tomato))
```

How can I do it? could not find anything that helps this

Answer (score 0):

`((Type=Food & Value1=Fruit & Value2 = Apple|Banana)` => 
`((Type=Food & Value1=Fruit & ((Value2 = Apple) or (Value2 = Banana))` 
is this helpful ?

Comment: No, because i have multiple such values

Answer (score 0):

ok I think you need something like this

```py
fruits = ['banana','apple']

print('banana' in fruits)
print('value' in fruits)
```

output

```
True
False
```

for your case:

```
((Type=Food & Value1=Fruit & Value2 in [Apple,Banana])
```